# Cross Origin Request Error

Tags: html, server, cross-domain

I am attempting to request font files from http://example.com/fonts - however as a result of my mod rewrite the request is sent to https:www.example.com/fonts

As a result of this I get the following error:

> Font from origin 'https//example.com' has been blocked from loading
>   by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https//www.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

(please note I had to remove "  : " from https because of question parameters.)

I do not wish to allow cross origin requests. How, if possible, can I achieve this without doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this extension for cross origin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

It is an extension for Chrome, you only need to install and then, click the button named CORS.